# Meaning of "Ignorance and bungling with love are better than wisdom and skill without"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, quotations

What is the meaning of the following quote?

> Ignorance and bungling with love are better than wisdom and skill without.

Comment: It means that they appreciate [*love*](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1+Corinthians+13) more than *results*.

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation is: "Being a fool who loves is better than being a wise and skilful person with no love in your heart."

*The wise and skilful one will do great harm to the world and live a miserable life himself when there is no love in his heart; on the other hand, an ignorant and bungling man who loves is basically harmless and he would live life happily. Of course, it is better to be wise, skilful and full of love.*

Answer (score 1):

If you have compassion for others and a genuine desire to help people, then your results will tend to have more value than any other quality that you could apply.